# Communication between asp.net MVC application and WCF services with windows based security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, security

I'm making an asp.net MVC application that communicates with  wcf services on IIS.
The asp.net MVC application works with a normal login mechanism (username, password). In the wcf services I want to log in (with this password and username) to get the windowsidentity of the user.(the security on the wcf services are windows based)

The issue is how can I communicate from the asp.net MVC application with the services in this way and keep the asp.net MVC application as stateless as possible (putting a password in the session state is definately not allowed)

Ideas about how to get this done are very much appreciated.

This drawing might make things clearer:
[image: Architecture Mobile App Website]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimentating I've found a way to do this.
I'll refer to the ASP.NET MVC application as the client.

Through a loginService , the client can pass the username and password. In this service this data is used to check if there is a corresponding windows account. If so a **guid** is created and this guid **along with the username and password** (both encrypted) will be **stored in a database**. The service returns the guid to the client which puts this **guid in the session state**.

When another call is made to a wcf service, the client sends this guid in a **messageheader** called 'id' . In wcf I use a **ServiceAuthorizationManager** to check the incoming messages. If there is a messageheader called 'id', this id will be used to get the corresponding username and password in the database, and with this username and password get the **windowsidentity** and then **impersonate** it.(this all happens before it reaches the service itself)

When the user gets to the service, he will be impersonated with his windows account.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article explaining step by step how to authenticate using an username/password in a WCF service:

http://blog.adnanmasood.com/2010/04/29/step-by-step-guide-for-authenticating-wcf-service-with-username-and-password-over-ssl/

It uses a custom [UserNamePasswordValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx) on the service side:

```
public class CustomValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (userName == "test" && password == "secret")
        {
            return;
        }
        throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Password");
    }
}
```

which could be configured as a service behavior:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfService.Service1Behavior" name="MySamples.WcfService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MySamples.IWcfService" bindingConfiguration="SafeServiceConf">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WcfService.Service1Behavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <userNameAuthentication
                        userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                        customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MySamples.CustomValidator, WcfService" 
                    />
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="SafeServiceConf" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="65536" maxArrayLength="65536" maxBytesPerRead="65536" />
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and on the client:

```
using (var client = new WcfServiceClient())
{
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "secret";
    var result = client.SomeMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly,you need a way to provide windows authentication to your WCF service. Following link can help.

[Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36289/8-steps-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-WCF-Ba)